# Почему выдает ошибку Route not defined?

Tags: laravel

Почему-то выдает ошибку Route [user.account] not defined, хотя route объявлен. Ошибку вызывает ссылка на личный кабинет в сайдбаре.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                @guest
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('auth.register') }}">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('auth.login') }}">Sing up</a>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <h4>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('user.account') }}">My account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('auth.logout') }}">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
```

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function account(Request $request){
        return view('user.account');
    }
    
}
```

```
Route::group([
    'as' => 'user',
    'prefix' => 'user',
    'namespace' => 'User',
    'middleware' => ['auth']
], function(){
    Route::post('account', [App\Http\Controllers\User\AccountController::class, 'account'])->name('account');
});
```

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` прописывайте, когда изменяете роуты, и будет Вам счастье. Начиная с 7 версии они кешируются.

Comment: Ошибка сохранилась

Comment: И ещё post на get измените в роуте. У Вас же ссылка обычная

Comment: Проблема была в том, что в строке `'as' => 'user.'` отсутствовала точка